# Sending arbitrary bytes to fgets from stdin

Tags: c, bash, fgets

I'm prompting for a user supplied string using fgets(user_input, input_len, stdin).  How can I send, for instance, the byte represented by hex \x04 to the program?

Comment: It depends on your terminal (or other input system you're using).

Comment: Are you having the problem that `0x04` is control-D is EOF?

Comment: @SteveSummit 0x04 is described as EOT in the ascii table, this is a char used by various serial transmission protocols as end of transmission. This, however, has nothing to do with ctrl+d on the console which on many systems results in an EOF on the input stream.

Comment: @Ctx Sure, but if I wanted to send the byte represented by hex \x04 to my program, I'd simply type control-D, and unless I was careful I'd get EOF instead, and that *might* be user6105782's problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$ echo -n -e '\x04' | your-program
```

*NOTE:* On POSIX `echo` only octal values are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the bytes you want into a file, you can run

```
your-program < file
```